# why Wireshark can't capture mysql login packets when without using -h parameter

Tags: mysql, wireshark

When I execute

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

in terminal command line, wireshark can't capture anything.
But when I execute

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

in this case wireshark could capture packets. See below:

[image]

I'd like to know what's the diff between `-h` and without it?
By the way if I use `-h localhost`, wireshark also can't capture anything.

Comment: Thank you for your beautifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default on *nix systems is for MySQL to connect by a socket file which will not use the network. This is why Wireshark captures nothing in this case. You should also see nothing if you use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

From the documentation:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
>   way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
>   network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
>   attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.
>   This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
>   number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the
>   local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by
>   using the --protocol=TCP option.

To capture the MYSQL Protocol

`mysql -u userName -p<passWord>  --host=localhost --port=3306 --protocol=TCP`

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me the link of this paragraph meantime.I had searched it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html